# Django Hashtags

Tags: django, hashtag

Hey StackOverFlowers :) I've been working on a blog picture app. I've been looking everywhere for a solution on how to implement hashtagging features for Django so that users can create hashtags for pictures and also sort/retrieve pictures based hashtags.

I have a looked at django-hastags on GitHub: https://github.com/semente/django-hashtags but even after reading the documentation, I'm so lost :(

I have a User model and I have a model for blog pictures. Below I've posted my code from my models.py for both of my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from bookmarks.handlers import library

class Bloguser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField('BlogPicture', through='Favorites', related_name = 'picture_favs')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('BlogPicture', related_name='likedby', blank=True)
    userPic = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    userCover = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    phoneNum = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class BlogPicture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bloguser = models.ForeignKey(Bloguser, related_name = 'shot_owner')
    postTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def json_feat(self):
     return{
        'title': self.title,
        'photo-url': self.url,

    }

def __unicode__(self):
     return self.title
```

From here, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to implement hashtagging? Sorry if I am not clear enough, please do comment and let me know so that I can make my question clearer for you and others! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

What about using a django tagging library? Such as [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).

Shamelessly extracted from the project documentation:

```
>>> apple = Food.objects.create(name="apple")
>>> apple.tags.add("red", "green", "delicious")
>>> apple.tags.all()
[<Tag: red>, <Tag: green>, <Tag: delicious>]
>>> apple.tags.remove("green")
>>> apple.tags.all()
[<Tag: red>, <Tag: delicious>]
>>> Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["red"])
[<Food: apple>, <Food: cherry>]
```

---

To be entirely honest, that [`django-hashtags`](https://github.com/semente/django-hashtags) library looks like it just rides the "coolness" factor in prepending "hash" to "tag", but doesn't look very well though out.

It does seem to offer a few nice functionnalities (such as list views based on tags), but that's something you could *easily* achieve with a `ListView` in a few lines.

Comment: oh wow really? If I had known I wouldn't have wasted so much time reading through the documentation. Could you show me a very basic example of how I can create ListViews based on tags? That would help me out a lot! :)

Comment: @rgjeya Use a `ListView` and override its `get_queryset` method with something like `MyTaggedStuff.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [wanted_tags])`, where you would get `wanted_tags` passed to your view in some way (an URL parameter, for instance).

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, you saved me a lot of trouble, you're awesome!